# iOS 6 pass data from TableView to Detail View

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, storyboard

I've a table view with some rows and each row has its Detail Disclosure button.
I want that when the user taps on that button, another table view (customized by storyboard) appears and shows some relative data.

From `TableViewController.m`

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[detailViewController alloc] init];
    //creating a parse object
    PFObject *checkin = [_dataSourceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //getting data i want
    NSString *trainNumb = [checkin objectForKey:@"trainNumber"];
    //passing the data
    detailViewController.trainNumber = trainNumb;   
}
```

From the DetailTableViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [_trainNumberLabel setText:_trainNumber];
}
```

The problem is that in the DetailTableView the `NSString` results to be null.

What I'm missing here? Thank you!

Comment: What about adding breakpoints and NSLog to debug your code?

Comment: are you sure in TableViewController.m it doesnt results into null

Comment: yeah in table view controller with NSLog i can see the corret value!

Comment: I've tried to put NSLog in both files. What i can see is that the NSLog in the viewDidLoad of the DetailTableViewController is printed BEFORE the NSLog inside the accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath of the TableViewController.
How can be possible?

Answer (score 1):

If this code actually compiles, this may be your problem:

```
DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[detailViewController alloc] init];
```

It should be:

```
DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
```

But you shouldn't be `alloc/initing` your view controller in the first place. When you customize a view controller in Interface Builder, you've got to instantiate it like this if you want those customizations:

```
[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyStoryboardIdentifier"]`
```

And you've got to set the controller's storyboard ID to "MyStoryboardIdentifier" or whatever identifier you want to use.

Also, as you've indicated in the comments, you've got a timing issue: your detail controller's `viewDidLoad` runs before you set the train number. A better approach would be to ensure that it works regardless of the sequence:

```
- (void)updateTrainNumberLabel
{
    self.trainNumberLabel.text = self.trainNumber;
}

- (void)setTrainNumber:(NSString *)trainNumber
{
    _trainNumber = trainNumber;
    [self updateTrainNumberLabel];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    ...
    [self updateTrainNumberLabel];
}
```

In other words, you configure your label in a separate method, in this case `updateTrainNumberLabel`, and when anything that could affect the label happens, e.g. the view loading or the number being changed, you call the method.

Comment: +1 for catching the alloc init on nil.  And the storyboard advice is good advice, but it's still okay to alloc/init a vc, for example, from a nib.  And if one is to use storyboard, it's also worth mentioning segues.

Comment: Yes. I just meant you've got to use `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` if you want the storyboard customizations.

Comment: it was my typo, in my Xcode it's Detail!
i put also instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier instead of alloc init, but nothing changed.

Comment: Nothing changed because you've got other issues. But you've absolutely got to use `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` in this case or it will never work.

Comment: I expanded my answer based on your some of your comments.

Comment: You're having a sequence issue. The solution I'm proposing makes your code independent of sequence. By following this pattern, you're less likely to have these types of issues in the future. If you want to minimize the lines of code, then you can set the label text inside `setTrainNumber`. Think about what happens, though, if your label depends on two different properties. For example, if want it to display train number and line. Since you can't set both properties at the same time, where do you put the code to configure the label?

Comment: ok but I mean, with your code, executing viewDidLoad will call updateTrainNumberLabel. where is the call to setTrainNumber?

Comment: You're already setting `trainNumber` in `accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath`.

Comment: `setTrainNumber` is just a custom property setter method. Also, in your detail view controller, you should access properties like `self.someProperty` not `_someProperty`. Doing the later defeats the purpose of using properties because you're accessing the instance variable directly, bypassing any custom property getters and setters.

Comment: i did as you suggested, this is what i get while i run the app http://cl.ly/image/3g3r172F0r0y

Comment: TableViewController.m http://cl.ly/image/1y2V091d1431
DetailTableViewController.m http://cl.ly/image/1o0V2Z1R3C1i

Comment: i've modified, still entering in the loop!

Comment: There's no loop in my code now. Double check, then please post your code. Or debug it.

Comment: the code is the same as before with your correction... i really dont get why there is still the loop...

Comment: Hit pause in the debugger before it crashes and step through it.